# Japanese SIM not registering on Oppo f19 pro

Tags: sim-card, oppo

My sister lives in Japan and has recently started using OPPO f19 pro. However, her sim is not registering on the device. She inserted her old Pakistani sim and it works but she obviously can't use the sim for texting or calling the people living in Japan. She can't even call on whatsapp. How to make the Japanese Sim work on this device? There is no problem with the SIM, it's just not registering on that device.

Comment: If the phone has been sold by the Pakistany network operator together with the telephone/data plan (contract) it may be SIM locked. Usually if the contract has ended (the run-time mentioned in the initial contract) devices can be unlocked by the network operator for free (usually after 1-2 years). Before you often have to pay an unlock fee.

Comment: Without knowing which SIM card provider, it might be better for your sister to also contact/visit customer service to troubleshoot it. Let us know if there's any update.